# How do I get the value of a named option of an already running process in Linux?

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, arguments

I run the following command.

```
ps -e -o args | grep destiny | grep UNIX
```

I receive the following output.

```
/path/to/destiny -r -m UNIX -t TCP -p 1501
```

What command can I use the get the value of the printed arguments (for example `-m` or `-t` or `-p`)? I would like to achieve the following.

`ps -e -o args | grep destiny | grep UNIX | <someCommand> -p` this should print `1501`

`ps -e -o args | grep destiny | grep UNIX | <someCommand> -m` this should print `UNIX`

`ps -e -o args | grep destiny | grep UNIX | <someCommand> -t` this should print `TCP`

Please note that `-p`, `-m` or `-t` may switch columns so printing with `awk` and choosing column by number is not an option.

Some more facts so that the parsing gets easier (I know it's possible I just lack the tooling knowledge).

- if an option is not present an empty string will be returned
- options that will be parsed will always have an argument/a value in this particular case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `sed`:

```
ps -e -o args | grep -e 'destiny.*UNIX' | sed -e 's/.*-t\s\([A-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/'
ps -e -o args | grep -e 'destiny.*UNIX' | sed -e 's/.*-p\s\([A-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/'
ps -e -o args | grep -e 'destiny.*UNIX' | sed -e 's/.*-m\s\([A-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

`sed -e 's/.*-t\s\([A-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/'`

- s/`search for`/`replace with`/`options`
- s is to search.
- .* matches any/all character(s) until we get to the "-t".
- \s matches any whitespace.
- ( begins a capture.
- [A-Z0-9]* matches any capital letter and any number of any length.
- ) ends the capture.
- .* matches the remainder of the characters in the line (if there are any).
- \1 replaces everything with the capture.

Comment: This method will fail when getting the value of last option (like `-p 1501` in my question). How do I express \s (whitespace) OR $ (end of line) at the end?

Comment: No it won't. There is no white space at the end of the sed search.  `.*` is any number of characters including nothing at all.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The string I tested was not upper case.

Comment: There was a typo in my grep statement.  The comma should've been a period. Sorry about that

Answer (score 5):

That is not possible in general because only the command itself knows how to parse its own arguments. Taking your example:

```
/path/to/destiny -r -m UNIX -t TCP -p 1501
```

`-p` could be an option that takes no argument (like a boolean: it enables or disables some behaviour) in which case `1501` would be a positional argument (like a filename or something). Or `-p` could be an option that takes an argument, and its argument is `1501`. There's no way to know which it is!

The argument vector is just a list of zero or more strings. There is no meaning attached to those strings indicating which ones are options, which ones are arguments to those options, and which ones are non-option arguments.

Even the `-r` option in your example cannot be generically parsed for certain. Given that `-r` is followed immediately by another string that begins with `-`, it's overwhelmingly likely that `-r` is an option that takes no argument (like a boolean that enables or disabled some behaviour) but actually that's not 100% certain. `-r` could be an option that takes an argument and `-m` would be its argument. Or the command might not follow normal UNIX conventions at all, and `-r` is not an option at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep`:

```
~$ echo "/path/to/destiny -r -m UNIX -t TCP -p 1501" | grep -oP -- '-t \K[^ ]+'
TCP
~$ echo "/path/to/destiny -r -m UNIX -t TCP -p 1501" | grep -oP -- '-p \K[^ ]+'
1501
```

(you may have/want to use things like `\s` instead of one space: `grep -oP -- '-p\s\K[^\s]+'`)

The `-o` means "print only the matching", the `\K` will reset the start.

Note that this will only handle simple cases (see [Celada](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207079/60965)'s answer for why).

Another way, using look-behind:

```
grep -oP -- '(?<=-p )[^ ]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python one-liner. (I'm using python because perl and awk don't have a simple way to get the position of a value in a list.)

```
ps -eo args | grep '/path/to/destiny' | 
     python -c 'x=input().split(); print(x[ x.index("-p")+1 ])'
```

It will work as long as the arguments you're trying to extract do not contain spaces.